# Can I print my own Lego bricks?

Tags: legal, bricks

Assuming I've 3D design (or I've created one) which looks very similar to Lego bricks, I am allowed to 3D print them for my personal use?

Do I need to obtain some permission to do so, because of some patents? Or how does it work?

Comment: I am not sure this is a good question. There seems to be a dislike for law-related issues, and in this case 3D printing seems to have little to do with the issue at hand. There's no difference between this question and "Can I make my own Lego bricks? (using any method)". Votes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/32/are-questions-involving-legal-issues-and-3d-printing-on-topic

Comment: Seriously? This is waaay more a legal question.

Comment: I think it's close enough to be ok.

Comment: This is all focused on patents, and permission, and I don't see this one as a good legal question.

Comment: To the users who would like this question to be reopened. Why do you think it should?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The patents that cover Lego bricks have expired, so you are free to print bricks using the same interlocking system. You are even allowed to offer such prints commercially.

What is not allowed (and a violation of trademark law) is to call them "Lego bricks" or use Lego's logo. "Compatible with Lego" on the other hand, would be fine.